# Decision tree Levels in factors of new data do not match original data

Tags: r, tree, decision-tree

I have this dataset:

```
head(mydata)
chr    start     stop strand num_probes segment_mean is_nocnv
chr18 52502759 52502887      *          2      -2.3870      YES
chr18 52508963 68598272      *       9546      -0.3843      YES
chrX 17018571 63154896      *      18479      -0.0448      YES
chrX 63161754 63812965      *        265      -0.5375      YES
chrX 63816350 66632343      *       1071       0.1047      YES
chrX 66632547 67941468      *        558      -0.5452      YES

sapply(mydata, class)
     chr        start         stop       strand   num_probes segment_mean     is_nocnv 
"factor"    "integer"    "integer"     "factor"    "integer"    "numeric"     "factor"
```

My decision tree is used for predict if new "sample" `is_nocnv` is `YES` or `NO`

I create the predict tree and then I insert this new sample:

```
chr1 <- "chr18"
start1 <- as.integer(52502759)
stop1 <- as.integer(52502887)
strand1 <- "*"
num_probes1 <- as.integer(2)
segment_mean1 <- as.numeric(-2.387)
testData <- data.frame(chr = chr1, start = start1, stop = stop1, strand = strand1, 
    num_probes = num_probes1, segment_mean = segment_mean1, is_nocnv = "")

testPred <- predict(albero, newdata = testData)
table(testPred, testData$is_nocnv)
```

and I obtain this error:

```
> testPred <- predict(albero, newdata = testData)
Error in checkData(oldData, RET) : 
 Levels in factors of new data do not match original data
> table(testPred,testData$is_nocnv)
 Error in table(testPred, testData$is_nocnv) : 
  all arguments must have the same length
```

I modify my code with this line:

```
testData <- data.frame(chr=chr1,start=start1,stop=stop1,strand=strand1,num_probes=num_probes1,segment_mean=segment_mean1,is_nocnv=levels=2)
```

The code produces a result even if it is not what is expected and returns the following error

```
Errore: unexpected '=' in "testData <- data.frame(chr=chr1,start=start1,stop=stop1,strand=strand1,num_probes=num_probes1,segment_mean=segment_mean1,is_nocnv=levels="
```

Comment: You have a different number of levels in your training and test set, make sure you have all levels in both sets.

Comment: chr1 and strand1 are character type. You might want them to be factors.

Comment: @Ankur if i write: chr1 <- as.factor("chr18") and strand1 <- as.facror("*") I have the same error

Comment: @user2974951  how can i control?

Comment: Divide your data into training and test set randomly, for ex. with `sample()`, this will keep all your levels in your data even if they are not present in a data set.

Comment: try removing (is_nocnv="") the last argument from data.frame function. you dont need the dependent in the test sample anyways. That is probably considering it as a new level.

Comment: @user2974951 I just insert this split: set.seed(1234)
ind <- sample(2,nrow(mydata),replace=TRUE, prob= c(0.7,0.3))
trainData <- mydata[ind==1,]
testData <- mydata[ind==2,]

Comment: @Ankur unfortunately even removing that piece does not work

Comment: The statement that causes the error has the argument `is_nocnv=levels=2)`.  I don't know what you meant here, but that is not syntactically correct. You can't have things that look like `A=B=C`.

Comment: hi @G5W i try this instruction for resolve this error : "Levels in factors of new data do not match original data"